# NHibenate assembly load problem

Tags: nhibernate

I have problem on NHibenate assembly load problem.

error details :- 
"Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Most likely an assembly version mismatch. Check all your dependencies.

Comment: I Checked with assembly version all have same version

Comment: If you use fluentnhibernate or the old nhibernate.linq provider, or other projects from nhibernate contrib, make sure they are compiled against your current nhibernate assembly - which i'm guessing is 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Did you also reference

- Iesi.Collections
- Castle.DynamicProxy2
- Antlr3.Runtime

Comment: And we don't usually reference the above. Once the NHibernate dll is in the same folder as its dependencies you should only have to reference the NHibernate dll

Comment: Sure, you don't need to reference them. But if you do they get copied to the out folder.

Comment: Yes I also reference above DLL and all DLL's in one folder